# Simplification of the expression using De-Morgan's rule

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Simplify the following expressions to the simplest expression using De Morgan’s
theorem and Boolean algebra.

## ¬(A(¬(B+¬C))D)=¬(AD(¬(B+¬C))

```
          =¬(AD)+¬(¬(B+¬C))
          =¬(AD)+(B+¬C)
          =¬(AD)+B+¬C
```

is the solution correct?

Many thanks!

Comment: Not clear... Maybe you have to show that LHS=RHS... You can go one step further : $¬(AD)=¬A+¬D$

Comment: Actually I'm suppose to simplify the expression i.e. ¬(A(¬(B+¬C)D))

Comment: If so, you need one step only : $¬(A(¬(B+¬C)D)) = ¬A + (B+¬C) + ¬D$.

Comment: Actually the expression is ¬(A(¬(B+¬C))D).sorry about the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am reading this as:

$\neg (A \land \neg (B \lor \neg C) \land D)$

which by DeMorgan would be:

$\neg A \lor (B \lor \neg C) \lor \neg D$

i.e.

$\neg A + B + \neg C + \neg D$

Comment: Thanks a lot!This was very helpful!